# Может быть пояснением (и обособляться), а может и не быть. Просьба проверить

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, пояснительные

Все варианты верные?

> Разница (подобного явления и противоположенных ситуаций) почти всеми бонзами должна пониматься.
>
> Разница, подобного явления и противоположенных ситуаций, почти всеми бонзами должна пониматься.
>
> Разница подобного явления и противоположенных ситуаций почти всеми бонзами должна пониматься.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81663/discussion-on-question-by-keny-valisamin-----).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложение более чем странное. Не могу понять, в каком контексте его можно использовать. Варианты все неверные. Попробую подкорректировать.

**А.** Правильно: ***противоположных*** ситуаций.

**Б.**  [РАЗНИЦА](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0), -ы; ж.
**1.** Несходство, различие в чём-либо.
Р. возрастов, характеров, взглядов. Р. в весе, в цене. Р. в возрасте, во вкусах, во времени. Р. в условиях жизни. Р. между детьми, между сыном и дочерью. Р. между постройками существенная.
**Видеть, понимать, объяснить разницу в чём-л., между кем-, чем-л.** Р. между кем-, чем-л. состоит, заключается в чём-л., бросается в глаза. Обратить внимание на разницу в чём-л., между кем-, чем-л.
**2.** Величина, число, являющиеся разностью между двумя числами, величинами.

В Вашем предложении по смыслу получается:
из подобного явления отнимаем (= вычитаем) противоположные ситуации, получаем разницу. Абсурд!

**В.** Должна пониматься почти всеми. "Почти" — лишнее слово.

1. Разница между подобным явлением и противоположными ситуациями должна пониматься всеми бонзами.
2. Эта разница (между подобным явлением и противоположными ситуациями) должна пониматься всеми бонзами.

Comment: А почему можно обособлять скобками, но нельзя запятыми (пусть тоже с добавлением слова "эта")?

Comment: Вот-вот, мы к этому и пришли. Сейчас добавлю.

Comment: @KenyValisamin, вставные конструкции, за исключением редких случаев, запятыми не отделяются.

Comment: @Серж, ну а почему это не может быть пояснительным оборотом (которые обособляются запятыми)? Учитывая то, что в контексте эту "разницу" мы уже описывали.

Comment: @ Keny Valisamin, пояснительный оборот - это обозначение одного и того же понятия другими словами. Чтобы уточнить, сделать более ясным определяемое слово. Перед пояснительным членом предложения обычно стоят слова именно, а именно, то есть (при их отсутствии в предложении эти слова могут быть вставлены): ***Она была воспитана no-старинному,  то есть окружена мамушками, нянюшками, подружками и сенными девушками (П.);***

Comment: @Серж, подходит.  

Эта разница, **то есть** то, что между... Эта разница, **а именно** то, что между...  

"Эта разница" и (то, что) "между подобным явлением и противоположными ситуациями" – может представляться как одно и то же. Более того, по факту я это и имел в виду. В контексте уже подробно описывалось явление, которое здесь называется подобными, а так же противоположенные ситуации описывались. Поэтому в данном предложении мне даже не показалось нужным добавлять "эта", ибо есть же пояснение сразу.

Comment: *Предложение более чем странное. Не могу понять, в каком контексте его можно использовать* - да тут мода пошла из каких-то виртуальных реальностей терминологию использовать... Может игра опять какая компьютерная.

Comment: Ну-у, я сделала все, что могла, ― чтобы придать предложению "человеческий" вид.

Comment: *чтобы придать предложению "человеческий" вид.* - боюсь, это не входит в планы автора. На вопросы, имхо, надо отвечать так, как они поставлены. А иначе - испорченный телефон.

Comment: Ой, забыл совсем. Разница - она не обязательно "между чем и чем". Она вполне может быть и "чего и чего". Так что тут вы немного поторопились править грамматику. Эта ошибка - максимум стилистическая. Остальных ошибок это, разумеется, не отменяет.

Answer (score 1):

Верны первый и третий варианты.

В Первом варианте часть "подобного явления и противоположенных ситуаций" воспринимается как вставная конструкция. Т. е. попутное замечание. В третьем варианте высказывание включается в основной текст.

В втором случае на постановку запятой нет никаких оснований. Даже если считать вставной конструкцией.

P.S. Хотя предложение стилистически не очень корректно.

Answer (score 1):

Все фразы неправильные.

1. С точки зрения грамматики и орфографии ошибочными являются написание слова "противоположный" (теоретически слово "противоположенный" существует, но оно в переносном смысле не используется) и ничем не мотивированное обособление в втором примере.
2. Слова "бонза" используется в неверном контексте. Да, есть одно, не самое ходовое, значение связанное с семой "надменный", но он без контекста совершенно неупотребимо. Непонятно, о каких бонзах идет речь.